# Many requests to /php_fpm_status and server unresponsive

Tags: php, apache, http, ddos, http-status-code-503

The server became very slow and unresponsive and I restarted apache and nginx a few times.
I looked in my Apache mod_status page and I seen 10-20  requests to `/php_fpm_status` , besides 100-200 normal requests (timing out) to normal website urls.

- Does Apache or PHP make requests to `/php_fpm_status` when [re]starting the web server ?
- Or requests to `/php_fpm_status` are more likely abusive requests from outside ?

Comment: Do you have a server monitoring tool, since i can only imagine a scenario where a request going to `/php_fpm_status` when the server is restarted. What do the server logs say, can you post it?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP site we can see that:

> For security the FPM status page should be restricted to internal requests or known client IPs only as the page reveals request URLs and information about available resources.

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/fpm.status.php

You can disable the FPM status safely if you don't need it.